# Github Pullrequest shows changes not yet included

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I cloned my fork of a public repository and made some changes; and then created a pull request.

However, any changes I pushed to my fork after I created that pull request  are also being included in the pull request, even though I never requested them to be included?

[image]

Why is Git showing the changes that I did not create a pull request for?
How can I avoid it?

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit so its easier to see what you are asking. Note that when you create a copy on github of a repository - you are creating a _fork_ not a _branch_ (the button at the top right of the repository that you click is also called fork).  A fork is a _independent_ copy of a repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub pull requests are for a single *branch*.

They will automatically include all commits push to that branch.

You should make a separate branch for each independent change.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: Exactly.  He didn't understand that.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I did not know that. Should I make those branches in my local repository or my repository on github? Also will it not create a lot of branches? If I understand it right every branch will cause a identical copy to be created. I am sorry if my questions are naive.

Comment: @Ayusman: Git branches have no overhead (they're just pointers to commits).  You can make branches wherever you want, although you will want to push them to GitHub if you want to make pull requests or work on multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks, I did not know that. Should I make those branches in my local
>   repository or my repository on github? Also will it not create a lot
>   of branches? If I understand it right every branch will cause a
>   identical copy to be created. I am sorry if my questions are naive.

A branch is not a "copy" of the repository. It just creates a separate history to track changes; and as such it does not increase the disk space used (if that's your concern - I know people new to git seem to think this).

In addition, when you create a pull request from a branch and your pull request is accepted - github will offer you the option to delete that branch (since the changes are now merged into the master):

[image]